# What's the meaning of this Makefile statement?

Tags: makefile

```
${COMPILE_PATH}/%.c.d:%.cpp
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) ${CFLAGS_NDBG} -MM -E $^ > $@
@sed 's/.*\.o/$(subst /,\/, $(dir $@))&/g' $@ >$@.tmp
@mv $@.tmp $@
```

`$(subst /,\/, $(dir $@))`, I don't understand this statement, `subst`'s second argument is `\/`, why? change `/` to `\/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is being used in a `sed` command where a bare `/` would be seen as the end of the `s///` command.

That being said an alternate solution (assuming you could make any assurances about what characters are legal in the directory name) would have been to have used a different delimiter for `s///` such as `;` (i.e. `s;.*\.o;$(dir $@)&;g`) or `!` (i.e. `s!.*\.o!$(dir $@)&!g`)

Comment: thanks, why `subst`'s first argument `/` is not prefixed by \?

Comment: Because `/` isn't special to make in this context so it doesn't need to be escaped. That is a literal replacement of `/` with `\/` in the value of `$(dir $@)`.

Answer (score 2):

The slashes in the path need to be escaped  because the `sed` script uses slashes as regex separators. An  unescaped slash would terminate the substitution expression prematurely.

However, a better way to  solve this would be to use an  alternate separator -- `sed` helpfully allows you to use any puncuation character here; slash is just a common default.

The temporary file is also a bit of a wart which can easily be avoided.

```
${COMPILE_PATH}/%.c.d:%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) ${CFLAGS_NDBG} -MM -E $^ \
    | sed 's|.*\.o|$(dir $@)/&|g' >$@
```

(I'm guessing the `g` flag is actually also completely superfluous here.)

Comment: I was initially going to *strongly* suggest using an alternate delimiter like this but in the context of directory paths escaping slashes is actually safer. They cannot appear in directory component paths but virtually every other character/byte can. So I toned it down a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they're changing the / to the escaped version.

Comment: The question was "why" not "what".